# Match 'State' text if written out or 2 digit?

Tags: regex, icu, street-address

New user, not much experience with regex.

I cannot match the state in the following text:

```
Lead status

53 W 70th St
New York, New York 10023
```

I have the following code

Lead status\s+(\w+.*)\v+(\w+[^,]+).*(\d{5})

I'd like to end up with 
Street Address,
City,
State (whether spelled out or 2 digits),
Zip

I am only getting 
Street Address,
City,
Zip

I appreciate any help.
Cheers

Comment: there are different flavors of regex - which one are you using? php? perl? c#? python? javascript? ... please add the respective tag to it

Comment: [Falsehoods programmers believe about addresses](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/)

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/AgTL9C/1